# How to fix `Value of type '[ReceiptInfo]' (aka ...) has no member 'compactMap'`?

Tags: swift

I'm working on a project which is build on Swift3, then upgraded to Swift 4. By switching `Toolchain > Swift Development Snapshot` to `XCode 9.2`, XCode shows 3 errors related to `compactMap`:

ERROR: Value of type '[ReceiptInfo]' (aka 'Array>') has no member 'compactMap'

```
let receiptItems = nonCancelledReceiptsInfo.compactMap { ReceiptItem(receiptInfo: $0) }

return receiptItems.compactMap {
    if let expirationDate = $0.subscriptionExpirationDate {
       return (expirationDate, $0)
    }
       return nil
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know so much about XCode and Swift. I need the equivalent Swift 4 code of it. I appreciate any kind help.

Comment: `compactMap(_:)` was introduced in Swift 4.1; in Swift 4.0.x it's `flatMap(_:)`.

Comment: @Hamish: Thanks a million! It fixed the problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Hamish, it's correct. compactMap(*:) was introduced in Swift 4.1 check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) in Swift 4.0.x its flatMap(*:) check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2905878-flatmap) but it's now Deprecated.

```
let receiptItems = nonCancelledReceiptsInfo.flatMap { ReceiptItem(receiptInfo: $0) }

return receiptItems.flatMap {
if let expirationDate = $0.subscriptionExpirationDate {
   return (expirationDate, $0)
}
   return nil
}
```